# nginx Won't Create File With Group Write Permission

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I'm following the python tutorial seen here ([LINK](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_mknod.htm)) with this code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
import stat

filename = '/tmp/tmpfile'
mode = 0600|stat.S_IRUSR

# filesystem node specified with different modes
os.mknod(filename, mode)
```

That works well. But I want to write the file with group write permissions. But when I change mode to "Write by group" mode:

```
mode = 0600|stat.S_IWGRP
```

(from [LINK2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm)) the file runs without throwing an error, but the file doesn't have group write permissions.  All the "mode" permissions work except group write and others write.

How can I get my python/uwsgi/nginx app to create files with group write permissions?

Comment: I haven't looked at the links, but mode `0600` indeed means group can't neither read nor write, if you want group read/write then try mode `0660`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, that's what the bitwise OR is for, to add group write permissions. In any case, I changed mode to "0777", and I still can't write group or others write permissions.  With "0777", I get:-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data    www-data       0 Jan 13 15:22 tmpfile

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mode = stat.S_IFREG | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IRUSR
```

from the help docstring:

```
mknod(filename [, mode=0600, device])

Create a filesystem node (file, device special file or named pipe)
named filename. mode specifies both the permissions to use and the
type of node to be created, being combined (bitwise OR) with one of
S_IFREG, S_IFCHR, S_IFBLK, and S_IFIFO. For S_IFCHR and S_IFBLK,
device defines the newly created device special file (probably using
os.makedev()), otherwise it is ignored.
```

P.S. try running `umask` in bash. If it returns something other that `0000` than it is automagically subtracting that value from what you specify (`man 2 umask`). Try running `umask 0000` then running your python script again!